# Imágen de base de datos a listview android

Tags: android, mysql

Pues estoy intentando mostrar en una listview en android unas imagenes que tengo en una base de datos y esta parte

```js
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null, true);
        TextView  androidos = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvandroidosnames);
        // TextView textView = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvurl);
        //  textView.setText(urls[position] );
        androidos.setText(androidosnames[position] );
        ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imgvw);
        image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[position], 100, 50, false));
        return  listViewItem;
    }
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

Como puedo solucionarlo?
Un saludo, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el bitmap que esta almacenado en tu array `bitmaps[position]` tiene un valor null, cuando llamas este método:

```
 image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[position], 100, 50, false));
```

trata de obtener las propiedades de ancho y alto  (`Bitmap.getWidth()`) pero como la instancia tiene valor null por esa obtienes el error.

Debes asegurar que tu array contenga valores de Bitmap diferentes a null.